Are 3 - 5 - 1 resolutions rare, or is it just me?
Asking this question feels stupid, but I used this 3 - 5 - 1 resolution in a song I'm making, and it sounds heartbreakingly beautiful, but when I search up this resolution online to see if anyone else has used it in a song I know, there is almost no one talking about it. And I am sure that it is a 3 - 5 - 1, the resolution is obvious. (If anyone wants to hear what I've made so far, I'd love to share it :D I am very proud of the voice leading.)
I'm the kind of songwriter to just put down whatever sounds good in my head, but I'm also the kinda guy who likes to consume all kinds of music theory knowledge and information, so I understand that the 3 chord is not used very much. Still, there has got to be a ton of songs that use this!
It's just a diatonic major scale chord followed by a 5 - 1, so if someone could give an explanation of why it doesn't seem to be used as much, then let me know. Also, it would be cool to hear some examples of it being put to use in popular music. Thanks!

Maybe related: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/127557

@user1079505 I guess that's pretty related to my question, seems that the iii chord just isn't used that much at all. I'm just surprised that the resolution isn't popular, it has an amazing 3 - 2 - 1 melody implication.

@jcfiggy I don't know, there are lots of examples in that other thread of the iii chord being used! Another that springs to mind the is the jazz standard 'my romance'. A iii - V - I in that order is a very familiar chord sequence to me from rock and pop. Perhaps not SO common in jazz because a lot of jazz is written with chords moving up a 4th on each change, but there you very often see it as a iii - VI - ii - V - I or some similar variation. I think you should carry on just going with whatever sounds good in your head, thats the most important thing anyway!
